# Use Session in Cronjob (Crontab)

Tags: php, session, cron

Hi is it possible to use sessions in a cronjob?

The Script I use is:

```
session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION['startwert'])){$startwert = 0;}
else {$startwert = $_SESSION['startwert'];}

if(empty($_SESSION['zielwert'])){$zielwert = 10000;}
else {$zielwert = $_SESSION['zielwert'];}


....


$_SESSION['startwert'] = $zielwert;
$_SESSION['zielwert'] = $zielwert + 10000;
echo "Startwert: ".$_SESSION['startwert']."<br>";
echo "Zielwert: ".$_SESSION['zielwert']."<br>";
```

But the Cron allways start set "startwert" to 10000 and "zielwert" to 20000 and it does not increase the values.

---

Ok now I have tried this.

```
/usr/bin/wget -O - http://mydomain.com/script.php
```

But the cron starts allways with 10000 and 20000. Any ideas?

Comment: Sessions rely on cookies, so to make them work for a cron job, you'll need the invoked task to be able to preserve cookies across invocations. This requires that you use an HTTP user agent such as `curl` or `wget` to invoke the PHP file from cron, rather than `php -f ...` or similar. Edit the question to include the line in your crontab which currently runs the job, and I'll be able to answer with a `wget`-based equivalent which preserves cookies and should therefore work with sessions.

Comment: Ok so only I must setup my cron like this? wget -q --spider mydomain.com/script.php

Comment: Why would you not just cache the "session" data to a local file that can be read/updated with each execution?

Comment: @MikeBrant An excellent question; I'm assuming the code in the question is an example not related to the actual cron job, and that the cron job is running some PHP code that's too large and/or complex to convert from using sessions to using direct disk storage, or that there is some other equally good reason not to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're invoking the PHP script from cron via `wget`, use the `--save-cookies` option; if via `curl`, use `--cookie-jar`. (If you're invoking the PHP script via `php -f [...]` or similar, then you'll first need to invoke it via `wget` or `curl` instead.)

For example:

```
wget --load-cookies /tmp/cron-session-cookies --save-cookies /tmp/cron-session-cookies --keep-session-cookies [...]
```

or

```
curl -b --cookie-jar /tmp/cron-session-cookies [...]
```

`wget` by default doesn't save session cookies, which you want it to do, hence the `--keep-session-cookies` option; `curl` by default does save them, so all that's necessary is `-b` to enable cookies and `--cookie-jar` to tell `curl` where to find them. In either case, replace the `[...]` with whatever options and arguments you're already passing to the program, and adjust the location of the cookie jar file to taste.

Comment: Good answer for the approach of using sessions.  You should also note that the session expiry would need to be set to a value greater than the time between scheduled script executions.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. PHP sessions are dependent on cookies (ignoring trans-sid mode), which really only exist in an HTTP context. cron jobs are running in CLI mode, so there's no http layer to deal with.

You **CAN** force a CLI script to use a particular session file by setting the session ID before calling `session_start();`, but there's no guaranteed that particular ID would actually exist when the cron job starts, as some other PHP instance's session garbage collector may have deleted it.

Comment: You have a point about session expiration, but not about cookies in general; `wget` supports, and IIRC `curl` also supports, preserving cookies across invocations by passing an argument which points to a cookie jar file. Assuming the PHP script in question doesn't absolutely have to be called in CLI mode, which doesn't appear to be the case from what's posted in the question, there's no reason it can't be made to use cookies and thus made session-aware.

Comment: Ok so only I must setup my cron like this?
wget -q --spider http://mydomain.com/script.php

Comment: yeah, but op isn't saying anything about using wget. I'm assuming the cron job is invoking the php script directly, with no http layer.

Comment: @MarcB Based on the asker's comments, it seems safe to assume he's using `wget`; in any case, if he's calling the PHP script in CLI mode, he's going to need not to do that if he wants sessions to work.