# Is it evil to modify $_COOKIE superglobals directly in PHP?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm working on a very special import script, which imports data from a external ERP-system to a ecommerce online shop.

The problem is, that the import script requires a cookie. If it's not possible to set a cookie, the script will not work.

My import script is working great, but only by executing it in the web browser. But if I'm using a `cronjob`, it doesn't work any more, because the script can't access to the cookies of the cronjob instance (a cronjob in my case does not support cookies).

The solution was to simply to modify the $_COOKIE superglobal:

```
$_COOKIE["adminhtml"] = "afsdfsO5sGJ6aFLh3iJRa1Cfo5lk9";
```

My question is, if this is evil or not? I spend two days to modify the webshop object, but it doesn't work. This simple script above solved all the problems. But are there server configurations, which will cause problems? Are there server, which doesn't support or use $_COOKIE?

Thank you for support :)

Comment: what is the cookie for? and could you not sure an alternative such as sessions? Another method is setting your cronjob to use curl to invoke the php script. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797885/use-session-in-cronjob-crontab for more details

Comment: It's a little bit complicated :) There is a third party extension, which requires a login to the backend of the webshop system. There are a lot of ajax calls within the web interface of the extension and my import script is simulating these calls. This works great in the web browser, but not with cronjobs (but it's required that they work in cronjobs). Sessions are no alternative, because I can't override the shop system unfortunately :) - But actually I don't want to discuss the solution =)

Comment: what about using curl or wget to invoke the script?

Comment: I'm already using curl including the cookie string, but this works only in browsers (it's even working in incognito/private mode firefox, but not in cronjobs) not in cronjobs in my case.

Comment: according to the link i posted. The reason a cron job will not work with cookies is down to the fact that runs seperately to the http process where as invoking the file using wget or curl the http protocol is supported

Comment: Instead of setting the cron job to use the php job. Set the cron job to use curl to get the file