# How to use seesion variable in cron job form cpanel - Codignitor?

Tags: codeigniter, cron

I want to submit currunt data in db every minute. For this I am using Cron job from Cpanel with this line.
curl -- silent https link of folloing file

This code is for cron.php (In controller folder)

```
  <?php 
    class Corn extends Mycontroller {
      function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
      }
      public function index()
      {       
          $insertData['news']=$this->session->userdata('academy')['academy_id'];
          $insertData['diyagent_users_id']='1';
          $insertData['link']='link';
          $insertData['days']='5';
          $insertData['to_users']='7';
          $insertData['till_date']='01-03-2021';
          $this->db->insert('academy_news',$insertData);
      }
    }
  ?>
```

Is it possible to use session here?
When I am calling this file using url inserting data properly, But it's not working using cron job.
please help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16797885/9326828

check this out

Comment: @Maroof what we need to use instead of curl in cpanel to access session?